# How to "skip" individual functions in a multi-function python script based on argument values

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, subroutine, goto

I am dealing with a MS batch (***.bat) wrapper that calls a python script with currently 5 argument values.

I want to feed `sys.argv(6)` to the python script in order to optionally  "skip" a certain function within.

To speak in batch language, i would like to circumvent a subroutine in `if %6=yes goto :function2 else goto :function1` style, just that it's not batch but python.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument to your script, e.g. in your bat file:

```
python myscript.py %6
```

Then in `myscript.py`:

```
import sys

def function1():
    pass

def function2():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'yes':
        function2()
    else:
        function1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to start using python **argparser**. It gives lot of functionalities, help and description:

**sample.py:**

```
import argparse


def function1():
    print("Function 1")


def function2():
    print("Function 2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='<Program Description>')
    parser.add_argument('-f1', help='Execute function1', default=False, action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument('-f2', help='Execute function2', default=False, action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.f1:
        function1()
    elif args.f2:
        function2()
    else:
        print("Please specify the arguments. Use \"python sample.py -h\" for help")
```

**Usage:**

```
#For function1:
python3 sample.py -f1

#For function2:
python3 sample.py -f2

#For help:
python3 sample.py -h
```

**Edit:** For your problem:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='<Program Description>')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--exec', help="Exec Parameter", required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    if str(args['exec']).__eq__('yes'):
        function1()
    else:
        function2()
```

For more info, visit [python argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)